# Magento 2 - Get data attribute value and check if has value per product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, magento2.2, attributes

I create one custom date attribute for my products in backend:

[image]

I need to get the attribute value in the products list page and to check if the product have any data added for the product.

I try something like this but is not work well:

```
$expectedInDate = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('expecdate')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
if(isset($expectedInDate)) : 
...........
endif;
```

What is the correct way to get data attribute value and to check if has data setup per current product?

The entire code:

```
<?php $timezoneInterface = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface');  ?>
<?php $expectedInDate = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('expecdate')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
<?php if ($StockState->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()) > 0 ): ?>
    <div class="stock available"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('In stock') ?></span></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if($expectedInDate) : ?>
        <?php $date =   $timezoneInterface->date($expectedInDate)->format('m/d/Y');?>
        <div class="stock available-in"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Available in:') ?><?php echo $date; ?></span></div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Did you try with `$_product->getExpecdate();` ? What about the flag "Used in Product Listing", is it set to yes?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help yes the Used in Product Listing is it set to yes

Comment: @Robert you can check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$value = $product->getData('expecdate'));
if ($value) {
    //print value here
}
```

Now depending on the attribute type you can display it in different ways.
if it's a text or textarea or int or decimal you can just `echo` it.
If it's dropdown attribute or multiselect you can display it like this

```
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('expecdate')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

if it's a date attribute you may need to format it:

if you are inside a template you can simply do

```
echo $block->formatData($value);
```

or

```
echo $block->formatDate($value, \IntlDateFormatter::LONG); //or MEDIUM, SHORT, FULL
```

if you don't want the time also printed and not just the date, pass the third parameter to the `formatDate` method `true`.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much Marius, I edit my post and I add my entire code there, all I want to do is to check if the product have qty > 0 to display in stock, else if the date attribute has value then to display this value, if the value is not set to display out of stock

Comment: I made the code like you said and everything seems to be perfect, thank you, is there any way to have the date format like this: dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: I don't think you should impose a format. just let the current locale display it's own format

Answer (score 0):

```
$att_value=$product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
if($att_value!="") { 
      echo $att_value;
}
```